# Assigning a new value to a iterator of a intrusive container

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, intrusive-containers

While working boost intrusive container splay_set, i have to reset local iterator member variables. Please see sample code below -

```
#include <boost/intrusive/splay_set.hpp>

using namespace boost::intrusive;

class Obj
{
    public:
        Obj(){};
        ~Obj(){};

        boost::intrusive::list_member_hook<boost::intrusive::link_mode<boost::intrusive::normal_link> > m_memberHook;
    private:
        int a;
};

typedef splay_set<Obj, compare<greater<Obj> >, member_hook<Obj, 
                splay_set_member_hook<boost::intrusive::link_mode<boost::intrusive::normal_link> >,
                &Obj::m_memberHook> > StorageSSet;
typedef StorageSSet::iterator   StorageSSetIter;

class Storage
{
    public:

        bool init(StorageSSet& sset)
        {
            // Error: "no match for operator= in ..."
            m_curIter = sset.begin();  ////<<<<------------- How to set new iterator
            m_endIter = sset.end();    ////<<<<------------- How to set new iterator
        }

    protected:

        StorageSSetIter     m_curIter;
        StorageSSetIter     m_endIter;
};
```

Intrusive container doesn't support assignment i suppose. I also cannot initialize `splay_set` iterator via member initializer list. There is so limited example on boost and other site. None gives clear answer to this question.

My question is what should i do to assign a new value to a splay_set iterator (and in general sense to a intrusive container.)

Comment: The first step would be to post your actual code. The one you posted isn't valid C++:"Class" is not a C++ keyword, list_member_hook is not defined, there are two consecutive commas in the typedef, etc. Assigning value to an invalid type is not going to work.

Comment: @Manish Re: edit, how will `(std::?)greater<Obj>` work without `operator<`?

Comment: @sehe I know, i am just to lazy to write lot of sample code :/

Comment: Oops. That's **[not just sample code](http://blog.jerryorr.com/2014/04/solve-your-problem-by-almost-asking.html)**. So, it's also not **[just being lazy](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/)** :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you get `const_iterator`s mostly is because modifying fields may break container invariants.

E.g. when building a set across elements of `struct { int key; std::string value; };`, modifying the `key` field through the iterator would lead to [Undefined Behaviour]

The clean way to update things would be to first remove, then reinsert the modified item.

If this really hurts performance too badly

1. reconsider your design (consider `mutable` members for non-key fields, consider including the non-key data by reference)
2. punch a hole in the abstraction by using `const_cast<>` to cast away the const. **DANGER** Don't pass this reference to any other party, because they will break the container invariants since they might not know to leave the key fields alone

Comment: I am not sure if StorageSSetIter in above code is const_iterator. I was thinking that in intrusive container assignment operator is private as it will lead to a new copy which will defeat purpose for using intrusive container. 
This design is due to the fact that i have to support multiple services that operate on different data structure. I have to unify them in one interface with iterator pattern.

Comment: @Manish You're talking about different things at once. Copying iterators != copying elements. (Likewise, removing and reinserting the same element does not require a copy of the element and as such does not defeat "the" purpose of using intrusive containers (there are many purposes, by the way)). Finally, there's an easy way to verify the type of `sset.begin()`: just type `struct {} _ = sset.begin()` and closely inspect the compiler error.

Comment: Your comment makes sense in my context. Your suggestion has given me some points that i need to check from client side apis that i am using.

Comment: That is the exact problem that i was facing. Sample code was miss-leading and reflected what i thought would be the case but you figured the issue then and there. Marvelous. Thanks Man